# Published Variables not changing view when updated asynchronously SwiftUi

Tags: user-interface, swiftui, clean-architecture

I am implementing an application where I have an AppState that stores all data in relation to the application, Interactors that will call repositories and update the appstate with data recived, and repositories that are used to initiate data tasks for post/get requests. I have given a more concise example of the general structure I have for my app.

Main App

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject private var diInjector: DIInjector = DIInjector()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            SplashScreenView()
                .environmentObject(diInjector)
        }
    }
    
}

class DIInjector: ObservableObject {
    let webRepositories: WebRepositories
    let interactorA: InteractorA
    var appState: AppState
    
    init() {
        let webRepositories = WebRepositories()
        let appState = AppState()
        let interactorA = InteractorA(webRepository: webRepositories, appState: appState)
     
        self.webRepositories = webRepositories
        self.appState = appState
        self.interactorA = authenticationInteractor
    }
}
```

The app state is structured as follows:

```
final class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @ObservedObject var userData: UserData = UserData()
    @ObservedObject var displayData: displayData = DisplayData()
}

extension AppState {
    class UserData: ObservableObject {
        @Published var loginInfo: LoginInfo = LoginInfo()
        @Published var userName: Name = Name(first: "", last: "")
    }
    
    class DisplayData: ObservableObject {
        @Published var testData: [TestData] = [TestData]()
    }
}
```

Interactors will largly be using data publishers and .sink to update the AppState once a get request has been recieved to then update appstate asynchronous. The appstate is always updated hoever the view does not reflect the updated data in the appstate. I have even tried the following which does not work.

```
class InteractorA: ObservableObject {
    @State var webRepository: WebRepositories
    @State var appState: AppState
    
    init(webRepository: WebRepositories, appState: AppState) {
        self.webRepository = webRepository
        self.appState = appState
    }

    func test() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            print("Ran")
            for _ in 1...5 {
                self.appState.displayData.testData.append(TestData())
            }
            print(self.appState.displayData.testData.count)
        }
    }
}
```

The view is as follows

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var diInjector: DIInjector
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("\(diInjector.appState.test.count)")
                Button(action: {
                    diInjector.driverShiftInteractor.test()
                }) {
                    Text("Add to AppState")
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

This view does not update the text whenever the button is clicked. However if I get ride of the DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter delay and have the code block run directly after the button is clicked the view is updated fine with the proper count in the appstate array. Why is it that for asynchronous changes the @published variables are not reflecting the changes in the view right away? If anyone has any advice it would be greatly apprecaited.

Tried a variety of things from restructuring how my DIInjector class holds the variables to passing the diInjector directly to each view instead of using environment objects. Unsure on how to properly update the view with published variables and reflect those changes on the view cleanly.
I think using .onrecieve could work but it isnt the cleanest approach as i then have to store data in each view again and update that whenever onrecieve is triggered for a specific value. Which i think defeats the purpose of using this architecture.

CODE CHANGES:

```
class DIInjector: ObservableObject {
    let webRepositories: WebRepositories
    let interactorA: InteractorA
     @Published var appState: AppState

    init() {
        let webRepositories = WebRepositories()
        let appState = AppState()
        let interactorA = InteractorA(webRepository: webRepositories, appState: appState)

        self.webRepositories = webRepositories
        self.appState = appState
        self.interactorA = authenticationInteractor
    }
}

final class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var loginInfo: LoginInfo = LoginInfo()
    @Published var userName: Name = Name(first: "", last: "")
    @Published var testData: [TestData] = [TestData]()
}

class InteractorA: ObservableObject {
    let webRepository: WebRepositories
    let appState: AppState

    init(webRepository: WebRepositories, appState: AppState) {
        self.webRepository = webRepository
        self.appState = appState
    }

    func test() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            print("Ran")
            for _ in 1...5 {
                self.appState.displayData.testData.append(TestData())
            }
            print(self.appState.displayData.testData.count)
        }
    }
}
```

The updated code still doesn't change the UI of the ExampleView at all see the gif below.
[image: Gif of issue. The button is pressed and diInjector.interactorA.test() is called and the value is updated in the appstate but is not reflected in the view in the text.]

Comment: `@State` is only for value types and is pointless outside of SwiftUI views.

Comment: Also, nesting `ObservableObject`s is not an out-of-the-box supported scenario. Consider using structs for your models.

Comment: Crikey that looks complicated! You're really fighting the framework here.

Comment: @AshleyMills I was trying to follow a similar architecture to https://github.com/nalexn/clean-architecture-swiftui. Do you have recommendations on how to simplify or change this? Is sticking with MVVM a better approach? I felt that since my app will have views accessing the same data it would be beneficial to have an appstate as a central source for all data that could then be manipulated from any view.

Comment: @user19402781 I initially went down the MVVM route, but now having written quite a bit of SwiftUI, I'm leaning the opposite way. In SwiftUI there's often no need for a separate ViewModel, and you could actually consider the View to be its own ViewModel, and maintain app wide state by using an `@EnvironmentObject` passed in from the top level. Of course, a lot depends on the app you're building, so don't to get hung up on a single pattern. I found this an interesting read https://azamsharp.com/2022/07/17/2022-swiftui-and-mvvm.html

Comment: @AshleyMills yeah the second approach was kind of what I wanted to go for. With the appstate. The interactors are merely just methods to update the appstate based on specific business logic. The issue I am facing is that if I update the appstate in the main thread (not asynchronously) the view updates fine with the published var. But if it's done asynchronously through a data publisher or using asyncAfter the view doesn't update as it should even though the published var changed.  Do you have any advice on why this could be happening? Also thank you for the read ill take a look later tonight.

Comment: DIInjector which is the State var does not publish anything .

Comment: @PtitXav what would be the best way to restructure it so that it begins to publish the changes? I have tried messing around with that and have had no luck so far. Appreciate the feedback thanks.

Comment: Some observations:  the `class DIInjector: ObservableObject` is not publishing anything, the
`final class AppState: ObservableObject` has **nested** `ObservableObject` which often gives problems,
 it also has `@ObservedObject` and that is reserved for whithin `Views`.

Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app 
[Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)
Restructure your code following the official approach (the link) and it will work.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Hey thanks for the reply. Could you elaborate on how DIInjector is not publishing any changes and how to fix this issue? I refactored app state to get rid of the nested `ObservableObjects` and `@ObservedObjects`. Appstate now directly stores the data. Again the issue still exists where async changes to any published var in app state are not directly updating the UI. they do trigger `.onReceive(diInjector.appState. testData)` though whenever they change so changes do seem to be published to the views but don't update the UI which is odd. Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: To publish changes in `DIInjector` you need to use `@Published var`. However, edit your question and show the code you have now.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine just added the changes alongside a gif that hopefully helps visualize the issue.

Comment: Avoid using **nested** `ObservableObject` and using them 
such as `@Published var appState: AppState`, this will give you problems. Similarly for 
`class InteractorA: ObservableObject` where you don't even `Published ` anything. 
Try converting `AppState` into a struct (without the `@Published` of course). Use it as `@Published var appState: AppState` in `InteractorA`.
Note that `AppState` in `DIInjector` is separate to the one in `InteractorA`.
Look at [Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)  keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed the issue potentially. This is what I ended up doing in the main of the app, that resulted in the issue being fixed.

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject private var diInjector: DIInjector
    @StateObject private var appState: AppState

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            SplashScreenView()
                .environmentObject(diInjector)
                .environmentObject(appState)
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        let appStateVal = AppState()
        _appState = StateObject(wrappedValue: appStateVal)
        _diInjector = StateObject(wrappedValue: DIInjector(appState: appStateVal))
    }
}
```

Making the appstate a stateobject and then passing it in as an environment object and into the DIInjector solved the problem. Now the UI is being updated properly.
[image: Solution Video]

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, where you have just one source of truth in the `class DIInjector: ObservableObject`
that `Published` any changes to the `WebRepositories` and the `AppState`. With `WebRepositories` and `AppState` as `struct`.

Keep the structure simple, no need to have multiple instances of `WebRepositories` and `AppState` in `DIInjector`, then again in `InteractorA`.

Restructure your code to use just `DIInjector` as in the example code.

```
// for testing
struct WebRepositories {
    // ...
}
// for testing
struct LoginInfo {
    // ...
}
// for testing
struct TestData: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    // ...
}
// for testing
struct Name {
    let first: String
    let last: String
}

class DIInjector: ObservableObject {
    @Published var webRepositories = WebRepositories() // <-- here
    @Published var appState = AppState() // <-- here

    func test() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            print("Ran")
            for _ in 1...5 {
                self.appState.testData.append(TestData())
            }
            print("\(self.appState.testData.count)")
        }
    }
}

struct AppState: Identifiable {  // <-- here
    let id = UUID()
    var loginInfo = LoginInfo()
    var userName = Name(first: "", last: "")
    var testData = [TestData]()
}
```